# How to specify save location?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save a PDF in a folder by using data from an Excel sheet.

When I run the code the PDF is not in the expected folder.

```vb
Sub createfile()
    'Declare worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' declare location to save file as string
    Dim sStoreFile As String
    sStoreFile = "L:\My Documents\ExcelTestDocument"
    
    ' declare filename variable as string
    Dim sFilename As String
    ' declare number of files to create
    Dim iFileCount As Integer
    iFileCount = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To iFileCount
        
        ' set the value of the file from spreadsheet
        sFilename = ws.Range("g" & i + 1).Value
        
        ' If extension has "pdf" then save as PDF
        If Right(sFilename, 3) = "pdf" Then
            ws.Range("A" & iFileCount + 5).Clear
            ws.Range("A" & iFileCount + 5).Value = sFilename
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFilename
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlType
        End If
        
    Next i
    
   MsgBox "All files have been completed"
    
End Sub
```

I am prompted with the MSG box saying all files have been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add sStoreFile  to the Filename:

```vb
 ' set the value of the file from spreadsheet
   sFilename = sStoreFile  & "\" & ws.Range("g" & i + 1).Value
```